# a simple dos batch script... ! working as intended

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
set /p ipAddress="enter Ip address"

:startOfScript

set i=
for /l %%i in (1,1,255) do (
ping -n 1 %ipAddress%.%%i | find "TTL"
if errorlevel 0 (
deploy_this.bat %ipAddress%.%%i
)
)
```

this script will ping all ip addresses in a given x.x.x.x/24. Its only supposed to do deploy_this.bat %ipAddress%.%%i if the ping of that address is successful. However, whats happening is the script is simply pinging every address in that particular /24 and regardless of it being up or not, doing deploy_this.bat %ipAddress%.%%i.

Comment: ping will not return an error if the ip does not exist, it will only return a non 0 error code when the ping process itself errors.

Comment: something is wrong with my conditional check, because if errorlevel 0 is seemingly being ignored.

Comment: no, errorlevel will always be 0 unless the ping process itself breaks so it's doing what is expected.

Comment: alright well how should i go about checking to see if the ping reply was from an online host, and then only if the host is online do deploy_this.bat %ipAddress%.%%i?

Comment: I looked into this ages ago and could not find an answer, but i'll attempt it again.

Answer (score 0):

`if errorlevel 0` is always true, unless you get a negative return code (because it checks for the error level being 0 *or greater*). You probably want

```
if not errorlevel 1
```

Comment: i tried
    ping -n 'known online host' | find "TTL"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo %errorlevel%
    )
    )

on a known to be online and known to be offline host each time the error level was not echoed...

Comment: Within your `for` loop? Keep in mind variable expansion and use delayed expansion when necessary.

Comment: variable expansion?? please enlighten me

Comment: Read `help set` and note the part about delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

For your code it should look something like this:

```
@echo off

for /L %%i in (1,1,255) do call :findit %%i
pause
goto :eof

:findit
    PING -n 1 192.168.0.%1 | FIND "TTL" > nul
    IF %errorlevel% == 0 (
        echo up
    ) ELSE (
        echo down
    )
goto :eof
```

I suspect the `errorlevel` was not working because the code was in the code block of the `for`, after extracting it and putting it in a `method` the `errorlevel` triggers properly.

In the method there is a simple `ping` which has its output redirected into a `find`.
If the find does not find the string it is searching for it will return a non-zero `errorlevel` which will then trigger the `if` statement.

for batch files, an `if` statment followed by an `else` must take the form:

```
if <condition> (
) else (
)
```

or it will not work.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a better version of the script, the second field of code has been tasted on my computer and works.

Comment: ok still having some problems, im testing this script now and i want it to echo 'up' if %errorlevel% == 0 else echo down... how would that look?

Comment: got it, one sec gonna try something

Comment: alright now according to your latest edit to the answer, it looks like i will no longer be writing the results of the ping to .txt and relying on the %errorlevel% of find within the file to be my conditional if statement... is that correct?

Comment: yes, I had that to avoid the ping writing to console, but now that i redirect to `nul` i can pipe its output directly to `find` without the need of a `result.txt`

Comment: my friend, i would love to accept, however we have a problem....
i changed @echo off to on, and the script is now appending the %%i to the :findit call instead of the ipaddress that i want to ping

Comment: I did the same for my example code and the problem does not occur on my computer. you may have changed something else which has caused this effect to happen, unless you mean you see the `%i` on the console? which is what should happen as the console does not resolve variables.

Comment: i just tried removing the %%i from the do call :findit
when i enter the ip i enter the first three octets, this becomes the variable %ipAddress and then the %%i should be appended to %ipAddress and a full IP address would be provided. now the script is pinging 10.167.99.%i

Comment: noticed i had an extra % infront of my ping -n 1 %ipAddress%.%i.
same problem as before though

Comment: i think the error is in the line 'for /l %%i in (1,1,255) do call :findit'
the variable %%i is being used for :findit, and not ping %ipAddress%.%i

Comment: you can replace `%%i` with `%ipAddress%.%%i` if you want to, dont forget the extra % though.

Comment: please move extended discussions to [chat].

Comment: @TimPost. Why didn't you remove those comments? what is the moderation policy about this one.?

Comment: @TimPost it would be great to move to chat but the "User does not have enough experiance" box kept popping up, so yeah...

Comment: @downvoter, it would also be good to know why my answer was voted down when it is a fully working example which correctly answers the question.